# How can i create DataValidationRule in Google DOCS API via gspread-formatting?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I need to create DataValidationRule: only numbers in cell.

```
validation_rule = DataValidationRule(
        BooleanCondition(???),
        showCustomUi=True)

...

set_data_validation_for_cell_range(sheet_, 'A2:B2', validation_rule)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set the data validation rule to the cells "A2:B2" as only the numbers.

I think that gspread doesn't use Google Docs API. [Ref](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.1.1/) From your script, I thought that you wanted to achieve your goal using Sheets API with gspread. And also, I thought that you are using a library of "gspread-formatting". [Ref](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-formatting/)

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, a custom formula is used for achieving your goal.

```py
validation_rule = DataValidationRule(
    BooleanCondition('CUSTOM_FORMULA', ['=ISNUMBER(A2)']),
    showCustomUi=True
)
set_data_validation_for_cell_range(worksheet, 'A2:B2', validation_rule)
```

- When this script is run, only the numbers can be inputted to the cells of "A2:B2". When the string is inputted, the warning occurs.

#### Note:

- This script supposes that you have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API. Please be careful about this.
- As the additional information, for example, when you want to use a number more than `0`, you can also modify the following script. You can see the detailed information at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells#DataValidationRule).

  ```
    validation_rule = DataValidationRule(
        BooleanCondition('NUMBER_GREATER', ['0']),
        showCustomUi=True
    )
  ```
- And, when `strict=True` is used, only the numbers can be inputted.

#### References:

- [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.1.1/)
- [gspread-formatting](https://pypi.org/project/gspread-formatting/)